# Composer install laravel every-time when I create new project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, frameworks

Each and everytime I want to create new project through this command

composer laravel/laravel_project project_name

composer starts to install everything form scratch .

Did I do anything wrong ?

Also, If I copy the framework from another project  that's the same as installing through the above command , right? [copying everything before doing anything to that directory]

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong, composer is the dependency manager of laravel, so every time you install or update a project composer fetches all the dependencies. check this [composer intro](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Also, If I copy the framework from another project that's the same as installing through the above command , right?

Yes, but I won't recommend it because the app key will be copied too so both projects will generate the same hashes. This can be good if the 2 apps should have access to the same database tables, but in most cases they should not.

If you use the compose command, compose will download all packages and won't cache them. A better approach would be the use of the [laravel installer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#installing-laravel): `composer global require "laravel/installer"`. It caches the packages you need for a project so it will be installed faster.